# Укороченный querySelector - вызовов функции цепочкой

Tags: javascript, оптимизация

Хочу написать аналог `document.querySelector('selector')`, но в одну букву - `q('selector')`. Реализация выглядит просто:

```
var q = props => document.querySelector(props)
```

Но querySelector можно вызывать в цепочке: `element.querySelector('sel1').querySelector('sel2')`, а сокращенную функцию так вызывать нельзя. Хочется получить `q('sel1').q('sel2').q('sel3')`

Похожая проблема рассматривалась [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1192462/), но там нужно обязательно добавить вызывать value()

---

*Добавление: Обычно укороченную функцию очень удобно использовать, но если объект определен ранее, неплохо было бы сделать "цепочный" вызов от объекта. Как я теперь понял, достаточно, чтобы объектом был только первый элемент, т.е. достаточно вызывать вызывать функцию, у которой "может не быть" первого аргумента. Главное, задать правильный вопрос!*

```
var q = (prop, props = prop) => (prop.length ? document : prop).querySelector(props);
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Написал даже красивее: `q('sel1', 'sel2', 'sel3')`, где селекторы ищутся по цепочке. И запись не сильно длиннее получилась:

```
var q = (...props) => props.reduce((el, prop) => el.querySelector(prop), document)
```

*Немного докрутил*, чтобы в качестве первого аргумента можно было использовать объект

```
var q = (...props) => props.reduce((el, prop) => el.querySelector(prop), props[0].length ? document : props.shift());
```

*Финальная правка ответа.* Я понял, что мне нужен только первый элемент, поэтому меня устроит небольшое расширение изначального варианта - `q(elem, 'selectors')`:

```
var q = (prop, props = prop) => (prop.length ? document : prop).querySelector(props);
```

Comment: это совсем не то, что ты хотел изначально

Comment: Думаю, мне лучше знать что я хотел)

Comment: Нет, не лучше ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @GrimCap Grundy прав :) Вы сами написали то что вы хотели, только что отправил правильную реализацию. А ваш ответ в текущем виде не отвечает на вопрос. ( Я минусов не ставил ;) )

Comment: @ΝNL993 у Вас нужно вызывать list() в конце, от чего реализация теряет смысл. И нужен не аналог querySelectorAll, а именно querySelector. Я минусов также не ставил

Comment: @Grundy Корректным было бы утверждение, что я неправильно поставил задачу, а не доказывать мне что я хотел ;)

Comment: @GrimCap, задача вполне совпадает с желанием ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Grundy это определенно не так. Нужное мне решение я написал сейчас

Comment: на самом деле  - это не так. Вместо решения из ответа, намного проще было собрать строку селектора и выполнить _один_ запрос `querySelector`.  `.querySelector(props.join(' '))` - что также исключает проблемы с тем, когда у тебя не будет одного из промежуточных элементов

Comment: В js файле сотня запросов querySelector. Ты говоришь, что вместо q('selector') нужно писать querySelector('selector') потому что что? Я согласен, что не совсем корректно задал вопрос, но убеждать меня в том, что мой вопрос не нужен - другая крайность

Comment: @GrimCap, не, в предыдущем комментарии, претензия именно к реализации через reduce была.

Comment: @Grundy var q = props => document.querySelector(props.join(' ')) ? Да, согласен, я про это действительно не подумал

Answer (score 0):

Наконец-то понял что вы хотели, вот реализация :)

```js
class MultiElement {
  constructor(selector, context) {
    if(context === null) {
      throw new Error('Context is null!')
    }

    this.el = (context || document).querySelector(selector)
  }

  q(selector) {
    return new MultiElement(selector, this.el)
  }
}

function q(selector) {
  return new MultiElement(selector)
}

// Пример использования

let element = q('.el1').q('.el2').el

console.log(element.className)
```

```html
<div class="el2 uncorrect_el2"></div>

<div class="el1">
  <div class="el2">
    <div class="el3">
      <div class="el4"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Внимание!

Такой способ **не** является оптимальным или быстрым, намного проще и быстрее будет использовать CSS селекторы. Вот пример работы с ними:

```js
let element = document.querySelector('.el1 > .el2')

console.log(element.className)
```

```html
<div class="el1">
  <div class="el2">
    <div class="el3">
      <div class="el4"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141143/discussion-on-answer-by-nl993--queryselector---).

Answer (score 0):

Возможно не лучший вариант, но я все же вкину его сюда, т.к способ все же рабочий и удовлетворяет условиям.

В функции `q` с помощью `querySelector` находим нужный элемент. Если этот элемент найден, то добавляем ему метод `q` и возвращаем этот самый пропатченный элемент.

```js
/**
* @returns {Element | null}
* у Element нет метода Element.q, дальнейший чейнинг с такой реализацией невозможен
*/
// var q = (props) => document.querySelector(props);

/**
* @param {string} - selector
* @returns {Element | null}
* Не использовал стрелочную функцию, т.к она не имеет this и берет его извне
*/
function q(selector) {
  
  const element = this instanceof Window
                ? document.querySelector(selector)
                : this.querySelector(selector);

  element.q = q;
  return element;
}


console.log(q('sel1').q('sel2').q('sel3')) // sel3 flag
console.log(q('sel3')) // sel3 wrong
console.log(q('sel4').q('sel5')); // TypeError
```

```html
<sel3>wrong</sel3>
<sel1>
  <sel2>
    <sel3>flag</sel3>
  </sel2>
</sel1>
```

Это, наверное, наименее замороченный способ.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141156/discussion-on-answer-by-neverm1ndo--queryselector---).